# How to JSON serialize NSData containing series of CGPath

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm currently attempting to serialize some NSData containing CGPath data which will then be passed to the cloud. I am attempting to do this in JSON but am struggling to do so. What would be the best way to approach this?

Comment: Got to json.org and learn the JSON syntax.  You can only serialize strings, numbers, bools, NSNull, NSArrays, and NSDictionarys.

Comment: I am aware that you are only able to serialize those types and therefore, I'm asking what can be done to get around this to achieve what I need. I am fully aware I will have to convert this NSData into another type that is coding compliant.

Comment: Well, you can, of course, convert an NSData to Base64 string format.  Or you can determine what data would be needed to recreate the CGPath and dump that in a more structured form.  It depends on what your needs are and the rest of your code.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the `CGPaths` to `UIBezierPaths`, they support `NSCoding`. They you can archive them singularly or as a part of an `NSDctionary` or `NSArray`, `Base64` to `NSData` and encode and add as string to the `JSON`.

```
+ (UIBezierPath *)bezierPathWithCGPath:(CGPathRef)CGPath

@property(nonatomic) CGPathRef CGPath
```

Comment: I saw some mentions about the NSBezierPaths, but for my case, Hot Licks solution is simpler and sufficient to implement. Thanks for your recommendation.